# Serving XML and HTML with Django

Tags: python, xml, django, http, http-headers

I have a Django App, that has to serve HTML-Files to normal Browsers, that understand HTML, and XML-Files to other clients.
In my views.py I'm trying to differentiate between the different HTTP_ACCEPT tags, the incoming HTTP request has. This seems to work already, since a normal HTML file is served as intended.

Only when i try to serve an XML file, i get an Error saying:

ValueError at /appstore/
The view appstore.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object.

Here is my views.py

```
from appstore.models import App
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers

def index(request):
  if (request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT'].find('text/html') != -1):
    latest_app_list = App.objects.all().order_by('name')[:5]
    return render_to_response('appstore/index.html', {'latest_app_list': latest_app_list})
  else:
      def xml_view(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          result = func(*args, **kwargs)
          return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize("xml", result),
            mimetype="text/xml")
        return wrapper
      @xml_view
      def index(request):
        return App.objects.all()
      @xml_view
      def get(request, id):
        return get_object_or_404(App, pk=app_id)
```

I hope someone of you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the else part, you are only defining functions. Not calling any. Hence the error

Comment: On another note, I see your idea of using a wrapper to keep code modular, but I would revisit the implementation. I am not saying it is wrong, but just not very readable, or maintainable.

Comment: The wrapper seems OK to me, but it should be defined once and used on the view function itself. Or you could use class-based views and inheritance to keep things organized.